# Execute command into docker image to launch solr exporter

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose, prometheus

I would like to execute a command inside the solr docker image to export metrics.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/monitoring-solr-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html

I tried with this :

```
    command:
      - solr-demo
      - sh ./bin/solr-exporter -p 9854 -b http://localhost:8983/solr
```

Here is the complete docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
    solr_data: {}
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:8
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - solr_data:/var/solr
    command:
      - solr-demo
```

I don't have any errors but the command to launch the exporter is not executed.

Comment: A Docker container runs one command and one command only.  With the syntax you’ve shown, it’s (quoting added) `'solr-demo' 'sh ./bin/.../solr ' ` — the entire `sh` string is passed as a single argument to `solr-demo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prometheus way to address this issue is to run the solr-exporter as a separate docker container or side-car and have it scrape the solr server.

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
    solr_data: {}
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:8
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - solr_data:/var/solr
    command:
      - solr-demo
  solr-exporter:
    image: solr:8
    ports:
     - "9854:9854"
    entrypoint:
      - "/opt/solr-8.2.0/contrib/prometheus-exporter/bin/solr-exporter"
      - "-p"
      - "9854"
      - "-b"
      - "http://solr:8983/solr"
      - "-f"
      - "/opt/solr-8.2.0/contrib/prometheus-exporter/conf/solr-exporter-config.xml"
      - "-n"
      - "8"
```

Using `"http://solr:8983/solr"` as the target for the exporter makes it scrape the container named `solr`.

The above exporter commandline was taken verbatim from the [docs here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/monitoring-solr-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html), you might want to adjust it depending on your needs.